# Importing header with C functions into Xcode proj?

Tags: xcode

I have a .h file with a single C style function:

```
void myFunc(NSArray *array) {
    ...
}
```

I want this function to be available in every file, so I `#import "Functions.h"` into my App-Prefix.pch file.

However, this gives me a compilation error `ld: 38 duplicate symbols for architecture i386`. What's the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You should not implement the actual C function body in a header file, just like you shouldn't implement Objective-C methods in header files.

**myfunc.h**

```
    void myFunc(NSArray *array);
```

**myfunc.m**

```
    void myFunc(NSArray *array) {
        ...
    }
```

Obviously, you should also add a `#ifndef` at the top of your header and if you decide not to use any Objective-C in `myfunc.m`, you can just as well rename it to `myfunc.c`.

**Update:**
The reason for this is that header files are collected from within multiple entry points in your program (multiple files). Then your compiler gets a little dizzy and starts wondering what function body you actually **want** to call (since there are multiple). A more obvious example would be declaring the same function name twice in a single C file. At the end, you should use header files to "describe" your function (add documentation and all that) and then use your main (.m) or C file (.c) to instruct the compiler what to do when that function gets called.

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution. What is the purpose of #ifndef in the header?

Comment: It makes sure that the same does not get included twice, thus causing problems. For example, when you include `"a.h"` in file `"b.c"` and in file `"c.h"` include `"a.h"`, and then include `"c.h"` in `"b.c"`, you would include `"a.h"` twice. As long as you're defining the same function types, the compiler does not really mind, but as soon as you're using typedefs, enums, etc. it gets really nasty.